# file not removed after uninstalling the msi file

Tags: visual-studio, windows-installer, setup-project

I created setup project from visual studio 15, The installer that I created is installing properly and it extracts a xlam add-in into appdata/microsoft/excel/XLSTART folder. So installation part is working absolutely fine. But when I try to uninstall the same using same installer, the xlam add-in file is not getting deleted from XLSTART folder.

> RemovePreviousVersion property is set to true

Can someone please help me why is this happening ?

Comment: That is a folder in the user profile? Is there another XLSTART folder per machine under **`Program Files`**? Can you use that instead?

Comment: You haven't set the file with the Permanent flag to true?

Comment: I set the permanent flag to true. My is with name having spaces in between(like name name name.xlam) is that the reason why it is not deleting ? because if I set name without space then that file is removed.